# Running Powershell CRUD script using Azure function timer trigger

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, timer-trigger

I have a Powershell CRUD script that I am trying to run using Azure Function on periodic basis in order to test the resource provider is working correctly.
I am assuming this is done by using a Timer Trigger.
Has anyone done something similar? If so, can I please see an example?

Comment: Yes you would use the Timer Trigger: [Create a function in the Azure portal that runs on a schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function)

Comment: Here is the [PowerShell Azure Functions Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-powershell) for running the PS Script with Timer Trigger

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment, I have opted PowerShell core in runtime stack, then I created the PowerShell Function as below:

[image]

Then I have read the available list of modules.
`Get-Module -ListAvailable`.
I have set the Timer Trigger for every one minute and the result is below:

[image]